# Chrome status element not refreshing during ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Can't see why this isn't working. I can see similar issues here with SJAX calls but I'm working async so AFAIK it should be working...

All this routine does is copy some of content of a CMS into a different area on the same CMS

The object allDocs is a json collection of pages

```
  $("#statusmsg").text(""); // the status msg I want to update
  $(allDocs).each(function() {
    // large chunk of page analysis stuff here - just regex and string checking
    $.get(this.page_uri, function(data) {
      // bunch of jQuery to extract the content, build the payload object and new page url
      $.ajax({
        url: newPageURL,
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: payload
      }).complete(function(){
        $("#statusmsg").text("Created new " + pageName);
      });
    });
  });
  $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    console.log(tableElems);
    $("#statusmsg").text("Done");
  });
```

And that's really it, but it takes a long time, there are a lot of pages to read and write.

At some point I'll probably use a progress bar but at the moment the text would do.

Nothing wrong with the program flow - it does what it's meant to do. The status messages display perfectly in firefox. But chrome? nothing. I get a blank statusmsg box and then, 2-3 minutes later when the work is done, 'done' appears.

Any interruption to the script - an error, breakpoint or alert updates the element at that point.

Comment: did you try logging anything to console on ajax complete callback?

Comment: Yes, no problem there. Writing the status update message to the console works as well - it's just getting the div on the page to update that's beating me

Comment: are you changing content of `$(#"statusmsg")` any where else in your section `// bunch of jQuery to extract the content, build the payload object and new page url` because the only possibility i can think of is you are changing `#statusmsg` again & again quite fast and your eye might not catch anything so try debugging your code by making ajax calls asyc so you can see what is happening.

Comment: What is the exact way you expect the status message to work? Exactly what happens in Firefox that is different than Chrome?

Comment: I think you'll find that if you change your text() to append(), your status message is being updated, but ajaxstop is simply populating the stausmessage so quickly after compete() that you don't see the message written within the complete(). Try using append to debug.

Comment: OK, Thanks everyone. After a lot of trial and error I found it. Another, unrelated bit of code (not written by me I'd like to add) had run async:false. I've seen this before - even though the async part has finished execution, Chrome seems reluctant to refresh the DOM until all ajax calls have finished. FF isn't so fussy.